# Platform Invoke from C# to C++ DLL

Tags: c++, interop, pinvoke

This is my first P-Invoke tryout and I am trying to call a C++ function from C# code. I created a c++ DLL through win 32 console application project in VS 2010. The code I wrote is shown here:
[image]

then I created a c# console application project and copied the c++ dll and pdb files into the bin folder. Here is my c# program and it throws the error shown in the image:

[image]

I am not sure what am I not doing correctly here. Thanks.

VVV

Comment: You can look at the DLL with a free program called Depndency Walker (Google it).  It will show you the exported functions in a DLL so you can check and see if it is built correctly.

Comment: Actually I found the solution. I need to put __declspec(dllexport) above the line int add...... in C++ code and need to put CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl as the second parameter of DllImport attribute. But thanks for the tool. I will have a look at it.

Comment: You didn't export the function. `extern` doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: The following code now works (shown for C# and c++) [DllImport("DLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int IntMean3(int a, int b, int c);         extern "C"{
    __declspec(dllexport)
        
    int IntMean3(int a, int b, int c){
        return (a + b + c);
    }
}